# Infinispan putIfAbsent(key, value, lifespan, timeunit)

Tags: infinispan

We are using Infinispan Server 9.0.3 for in memory cache.

And using  below putifabsent method to store objects in cache.
 myRemoteCache.putIfAbsent(Key, request, objectLifespan, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

However the above putIfAbsent is not storing objects in cache if objectLifespan value is greather than one month. I would like to maintain objects lifespan upto 1 year in cache.

Server Configurations are

```
<expiration lifespan="-1" max-idle="-1" interval="-1" />
                     <locking acquire-timeout="30000" concurrency-level="200" striping="false" />                
                     <file-store shared="false" preload="true" fetch-state="true" read-only="false" passivation="false" path="${infinispan.cache.persistence.file.path}" />

<indexing index="LOCAL" >                  
    <!-- Enabled fastest writer: NRT backend  Non-shared indexes :directory-based or near-real-time -->
    <!--The drawback with near-real-time is that unflushed index changes can be lost in case of a non-clean shutdown -->
    <property name="default.indexmanager">near-real-time</property>
    <!-- Write indexes in Infinispan filesystem - Filesystem based index, infinispan - Distributed Cache-->
    <property name="default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
    <property name="default.reader.strategy">shared</property>
    <!-- This index is dedicated to the current node -->
    <property name="default.exclusive_index_use">true</property>

    <property name="default.chunk_size">128000</property>
    <property name="default.metadata_cachename">LuceneIndexesMetadataOWR_xxx</property>
    <property name="default.data_cachename">LuceneIndexesDataOWR_xxx</property>
                    <property name="default.indexBase">/apps/infinispanserver/infinispan-server-9.0.3.Final/bin/index</property> 

    <!-- The default is 10, but we don't want to waste many cycles in merging 
            (tune for writes at cost of reader fragmentation) -->
    <property name="default.indexwriter.merge_factor">90</property>

    <!-- Never create segments larger than 128 mb -->
    <property name="default.indexwriter.merge_max_size">128</property>

    <!-- IndexWriter flush buffer size in MB -->
    <property name="default.indexwriter.ram_buffer_size">16</property>

    <!-- Make sure to use native locking -->
    <property name="default.locking_strategy">native</property>

    <!-- Enable sharding on writers -->
    <property name="default.sharding_strategy.nbr_of_shards">24</property>

    <!-- No need to be backwards compatible regarding Lucene version -->
    <property name="lucene_version">LUCENE_CURRENT</property>        

    <indexed-entities>
      <indexed-entity>xxxxxxx</indexed-entity>
    </indexed-entities> 
</indexing>
```

And using HotRod client protocol to communicate with server and using Protobuf datastructure.

Could you please suggest why putIfAbsent() calls are failing when lifespan is set  more than 1 month?

Comment: This sounds like the expiration being stored in integer somewhere along the path - as the expiration is handled in milliseconds internally and 1 month is more than 2^31 this rings a bell. Please create a minimal reproducer and file a JIRA https://issues.jboss.org/

Comment: Thanks Radim Vansa. I have raised Jira in infini span forum https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-8886

Answer (score 0):

In Infinispan versions prior to 10.0, a lifespan greater than 30 days was interpreted as a UNIX epoch time (probably because the Memcached protocol did the same).

This behaviour was removed in 10.0 ([ISPN-10032](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-10032)).